# Excel dynamic named range based on 2 columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a dynamic named range based on 2 columns of data.  The first column has either a blank cell or a 1, and the 2nd column has the value I want to return.  For example:

```
Col A  | Col B
-----------------------
1      | user1@email.com
1      | user2@email.com
       | user3@email.com
1      | user4@email.com
```

In the above example I would want the dynamic range to contain user1@email.com, user2@email.com, user4@email.com which I could then use in a validation etc.  I have plenty of ranges that use offset to grow / shrink as required however can't figure out how to achieve this particular scenario

Comment: They would need to be sorted for dynamic name range as you cant reference multiple selections like that, The pivot answer is best

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not tagged VBA maybe a PivotTable would help:

[image: SO19383131 example]

Comment: I was specifically after a DNR as I wanted to be able to use it for an in cell dropdown (validation).  I also can't use VBA as the end user does not have the security level